# JPlayer not playing music from localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I am trying to play music from `localhost` using `JPlayer` but it is not working on Opera.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        title: "Bubble",
        mp3: "demo.mp3",
        oga: "demo.ogg"
      });
    },
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
    swfPath: "js/swf",
    supplied: "mp3, oga",
    solution:"html,flash",
    wmode:"window" 
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there any error when you inspect the element in Opera browser?

Comment: Without more detail, it's going to be difficult to troubleshoot, but jPlayer suggests ensuring your swfPath is correct http://jplayer.org/support/. I see you've supplied a relative path; make sure that path is valid for the URL of the page you're on when you run the script.

Comment: Thanks now it working.... I changed two codes `swfPath: "/js/swf/",` and also `mp3:"/demo.mp3",oga: "/demo.ogg"`